# Getting the URL of the redirecting page

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a page to which users will be sent via a 301 redirect. Is there any way to get the URL of the specific page which redirected them through javascript?

EDIT: I can't use `document.referrer` because it is preserved or blank for a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions

If you have access to the original page

- and the target page is from the same domain, you can set a cookie
- from the same server you can set a session variable and add it in a comment/hidden field on the 301
- in either case you can pass the original URL in the query string

Comment: I was going through so much to avoid having to use a cookie, but now I'm just implementing that and it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You will get it in with PHP

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

EDIT: The HTTP_REFERER parameter seems not to be working with 301 redirections, so what I would suggest is passing by GET parameters the previous url if you own the previous page, or using a PHP session if you want to hide the parameter.

```
header('Location: http://example.com/?ref='.urlencode("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"));
```

or

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['referer'] = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Then retrieve the data with either

```
$_GET["ref"];
```

or

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['referer'];
```

These are server sided solutions, but really easy to use.

You can add them to your javascript right after getting them :

```
<script>var referer = "<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>";</script>
```

EDIT2: Just get the GET parameter with javascript, so you will not need PHP